# Conditions on parameters in Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, algebra

i have a system of equations in which there are two parameters F, G. **I choose F,G positive**. the code is:

```
G > 0
F > 0

Reduce[{(1/Sqrt[V (Z *H*P - V*MU)]) == (F*G)^(-1/2), 
  Sqrt[(Z *H*P - V*MU)/V] Z^-1 == (F/G)^(1/2), 
  Sqrt[(Z *H*P - V*MU)/V] H^-1 == (G/F)^(1/2), 
  Sqrt[(Z *H*P - V*MU)/V] P^-1 == (F*G)^(
   1/2), ((Z *H*P - V*MU)^(3/2)/(V^(3/2)*Z *H*P) ) == (F*G)^(1/2), 
  MU == 0}, {V, Z , H, P, MU}, Reals]
```

But i obtain this:

```
((G < 0 && F < 0 && V == 1 && Z == -G && H == (F G)/Z && 
     P == (H Z)/(F G)) || (G > 0 && F > 0 && V == 1 && Z == G && 
     H == (F G)/Z && P == (H Z)/(F G))) && MU == 0
```

Why? I choose F,G positive and why it considers all the possibility? Another thing is it finds the value , for example, of Z but it doesn't substitute it into the result of H and P.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inequalities standing by themselves have no effect on anything. They must be used as [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) (directly or through `$Assumptions`) in **functions that take the option `Assumptions`**. [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) does not use `Assumptions` so the inequalities must be included in the system of equations and constraints given as its first argument. Also, using the option [`Backsubstitution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Backsubstitution.html) will give cleaner results.

```
Reduce[{(1/Sqrt[V (Z*H*P - V*MU)]) == (F*G)^(-1/2), 
  Sqrt[(Z*H*P - V*MU)/V] Z^-1 == (F/G)^(1/2), 
  Sqrt[(Z*H*P - V*MU)/V] H^-1 == (G/F)^(1/2), 
  Sqrt[(Z*H*P - V*MU)/V] P^-1 == (F*G)^(1/
      2), ((Z*H*P - V*MU)^(3/2)/(V^(3/2)*Z*H*P)) == (F*G)^(1/2), MU == 0 , 
  G > 0, F > 0}, {V, Z, H, P, MU}, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True]

(* G > 0 && F > 0 && V == 1 && Z == G && H == F && P == 1 && MU == 0 *)
```

Note that the constraints are included in the result. If you wish them removed, use [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) with the constraints as `Assumptions`.

```
Simplify[%, {G > 0, F > 0}]

(* V == 1 && G == Z && F == H && P == 1 && MU == 0 *)
```

You could also use [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) rather than `Reduce`.

```
Solve[{(1/Sqrt[V (Z*H*P - V*MU)]) == (F*G)^(-1/2), 
   Sqrt[(Z*H*P - V*MU)/V] Z^-1 == (F/G)^(1/2), 
   Sqrt[(Z*H*P - V*MU)/V] H^-1 == (G/F)^(1/2), 
   Sqrt[(Z*H*P - V*MU)/V] P^-1 == (F*G)^(1/
       2), ((Z*H*P - V*MU)^(3/2)/(V^(3/2)*Z*H*P)) == (F*G)^(1/2), MU == 0 , 
   G > 0, F > 0}, {V, Z, H, P, MU}, Reals] // Simplify[#, {G > 0, F > 0}] &

(* {{V -> 1, Z -> G, H -> F, P -> 1, MU -> 0}} *)
```

Comment: thank you for the informations. i'm new on mathematica